# moderncv.cls not found on base TeX install

Tags: moderncv, docker

I am using this [kjarosh/latex:2023.1-small](https://github.com/kjarosh/latex-docker) docker container to build my own latex docker runtime. When I use XeLaTeX to build the moderncv tex file, I get this error:

> LaTeX Error: File `moderncv.cls' not found

I have tried to put `moderncv.cls' to path` /root/texmf/tex/latex`. It seems that LaTeX did not search the path: What should I do to add the` moderncv.cls` to the search path?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/36296

Comment: I assume the provider of this docker container may be able to help you. (E.g. tag docker yields 3 questions here ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker )

Comment: it seems I have to install the moderncv manually when package the container.